# Most significant bits of int in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm using `glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, n, 100)` to create 100 cylinders in OpenGL. Now I want to put in them in a simple grid in space. So each cylinder will be 10 units away from the next. Note that only only the x and z coordinates will change.

```
example cylinder positions:
1 = (0,0,0)
2 = (0,0,10)
3 = (10,0,0)
4 = (10,0,10)
```

I know that `gl_InstanceID` in the vertex shader will be a unique, sequential ID for each cylinder. I can't figure out how to use this ID to create unique, uniform x,y,z coordinates. I read that you can use the most significant bits of gl_InstanceID for the x coordinate and the least significant for the z. I don't know how to extract these bits out of the ID in GLSL.

So my question is, how can I extract the MSB/LSB out of the ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to extract bits from it at all? If you've got 100 cylinders, the general pattern for putting those in a grid would be to work in multiples of 10. The first 10 go in the first row, the second 10 in the second row, etc.

In GLSL, you would use `/` and `%`. The instance `/ 10` would be how many Z's it is, and the instance `% 10` would be how many X's it is.

So if the instance is 3, `3 / 10` is 0. `3 % 10` is 3. So it would be 3 X's and 0 Z's. For the number 94, `94 / 10` is 9, while `94 % 10` is 4. So 4 X's and 9 Z's.

You can scale the X and Z values you get if you want to put some distance between the objects.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.